# How to fix "integer argument expected, got float" error in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get an error when i run a code in Python 3.7 for generating a picture and changing pixels.

I haven't tried many options tho. I'm using Windows 10 with Python 3.7.3.

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new("RGB", (640, 480), (0, 0, 225))

for x in range(640):
    for y in range(480):
        img.putpixel([x, y], (x / 3, (x + y) / 6, y / 2))

img.show()
```

I expect the output to be an image with a orange and blue shading image.

Comment: [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](//stackoverflow.com/q/183853)

Comment: Try doing `img.putpixel([x, y], (int(x / 3), int((x + y) / 6), int(y / 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` performs exact division, hence you get a `float`

`//` does integer division, so you get a `int`

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new("RGB", (640, 480), (0, 0, 225))

for x in range(640):
    for y in range(480):
        img.putpixel([x, y], (x // 3, (x + y) // 6, y // 2))

img.show()
```